# Automatic next and previous navigation for static sites?

Tags: jquery, static, navigation, mootools

I have a static site with a series of pages that I'd like to add "next page" and "previous Page" links to. Linking the buttons to the next and previous pages from each page is not a big hassle but can be a pain to update and re order.

Anyone know of any handy solutions using jquery or mootools?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the format of your URLs? Do the pages go from example.com/sometopic to example.com/adifferenttopic or are they numbered (example.com/1 to example.com/2)? Do you have (or could you create) a database that stored the order of the pages?

Comment: How would any one page know what page should be next, or previous?

Comment: Now they have unique names....but all under the same domain and folder. they are all in the same unordered list. A database would be overkill. I like Andy's approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array containing all the URLs of the pages, then check the URL of the current page in the array and create the prev and next buttons with jquery based on that.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! I don't know javascript ... only html and css. 

Could the array be loaded with the urls in an unordered list? 

Can I hire you to do the job?  Anyone else interested? 

Thanks

Comment: Hi i've created a little example. Here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6934514/pages.zip. It's pretty straight forward, just edit the Array in the javascript.js

Comment: I forgot, you can of course create the array from an unordered list on your page. Here's an example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/RSPg3/1/

Comment: Christmas has come early! Thank you very much. What's your PayPal address? I got the first version working already!.... now trying the unordered list way.

Comment: Could you please post an updated javascript.js that loads the array from the UL? thanks!

Comment: Glad i could help:  andi3000@gmx.at || ok, 1 minute

Comment: Payment sent! I'm trying to get the array to load from my UL that has hyperlinked list items like this: 

<li id="budgeting"><a href="features-budgeting.html">Never Over Budget</a></li>
<li id="autopay"><a href="features-autopay.html">Painless Payments</a></li>

It isn't working cause the list item has a hyperlink tag in it. Simple fix? Thanks again

Comment: yes, change $('#pages li').each(function(){
    pages.push($(this).html()); 
 }); to $('#pages a').each(function(){
    pages.push($(this).attr('href')); 
 });

Comment: Killer! You made my day! Sending you an email or private message soon.

Comment: Thanks but i'm pretty busy on my own projects right now. But if you run into any problems I can try to help

Comment: Thanks, recommend anyone else?

Comment: I'm honored! One further improvement would be to create the list dynamically from the javascript instead of the other way around. So you wouldn't need the list in every file.

Comment: Thanks... planning on using it again on another mini site today! Blog updated to include the newest version.

Comment: Andy,  Would it be easy for you to convert this to support Internet Explorer? I seem to have lots of visitors (  more than expected ) who are using Internet Explorer. thanks for any ideas.

Comment: oh wow, ie doesn't support array.indexOf lol sorry. change line 13 (var current = pages.indexOf....) to var current = $.inArray(location.href.split('/').pop(),pages);